# Find which row/sublist a value is in

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out what row a value is in and am not having much luck. I have found lots of examples of working with columns and rows on stackoverflow but haven't been able to find this, probably because it's something very easy and I just don't get it. Could any one help me.

For example, I have a list of integers starting from 0 to 99, in 10 rows and 10 columns. What row does the value 17 reside in, assuming that I don't know the pattern of the values in the lists?

The list is like this

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], ...]
```

Comment: You mean you have a list with ten lists inside? Please clarify what data structure we are talking about here.

Comment: What do you mean by rows and columns?

Comment: if you mean [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] ...] then 17 is in row 1, column 7, indexing in python is zero based

Comment: so you access it as l[1][7]

Comment: @gkusner but how would I look for any value? for example where in the list of rows is 84? And what is the list is made up of 13 rows and 20 columns?

Comment: its zero based so the index of the inner list is the first value and the index to the element in the inner list is the second value so 84 would be at lst[8][4]

Comment: if the inner list sizes change it becomes an excercise in different number systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I'm assuming that you want to find the sublists a value is in within a list of lists where the values in the inner lists don't follow a specific pattern which would make computation of the sublist a value is in trivial.

Suppose we have a list `lst`

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [7, 12, 13]]
```

where each sublist is a "row". If you want to know in which sublists/rows a value is in (let's take `find == 7` for the demo), you can do:

```
>>> find = 7
>>> [x[0] for x in enumerate(lst) if find in x[1]]
[2, 4]
```

`find` is in row/sublist 2 and 4, counting from zero.

If you want to know the rows *and* the columns, you can issue:

```
>>> [(x[0],y[0]) for x in enumerate(lst) for y in enumerate(x[1]) if y[1] == find]
[(2, 1), (4, 0)]
```

`find` is in row 2, column 1 and also in row 4, column 0.